# XMLHttpRequest error not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xmlhttprequest, aiml

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml version="1.0.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<category>
    <pattern>BOTÃO</pattern>
    <template>
        &lt;button id="ajaxButton" type="button"&gt;Clique aqui&lt;/button&gt;
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                document.getElementById("ajaxButton").addEventListener('click', loadXML);
            });


            function loadXML(){
                try{
                        var xRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

                        xRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                            //Se o open-send funcionar e estiver ok, roda essa função.
                            if( xRequest.readyState == 4 ){
                                if(  xRequest.status == 200 ){
                                    console.log("Deu tudo certo.");
                                    console.log(xRequest.responseText);
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log("Ocorreu um erro durante o open-send.");
                                console.log("readyState = " + xRequest.readyState.toString());
                                console.log("status = " + xRequest.status.toString());
                                console.log(xRequest.statusText);
                            }
                        };
                        xRequest.open("GET", "http://penta3.ufrgs.br/~aliane/getuser.php", true);
                        xRequest.send();
                    }
                    catch(Exception erro){
                        console.log("Erro ocorrido: " + erro);
                    }
            };
        </script>
    </template>
</category>


</aiml>
```

When I run the script on the page, I get this error:

```
VM244:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at p (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Ja (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at r.fn.init.append (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at T (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at r.fn.init.html (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at Object.success ((index):78)
at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

I've read my file over and over, can't find where's the unexpected end of input..
Updated my Jquery to latest version, just to be sure(3.2.1), but no success...

The goal is to call this script from a ChatBot that's on development, when it's typed "botão", calls the script and ...
any ideas?

Comment: check what response you are sending from your backend

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR what do you mean?

Comment: check the response what you are sending from backend, i think there are some enclosed quotes are missing